Is it ideal to use get_parent() in Godot to change player velocity, position, etc?
I'm using Godot to make a game and I have a player that can dash if he has dash ability.
Well, I've made the dash ability separately that is not within player.gd script, I'm accessing player from the dash_ability.gd script, is it ok to just do that or not?
# This is dash_ability.gd script
extends Node

# Exported Variables
@export var dash_speed: int = 1500
@export var dash_duration: float = 0.2

# Internal Variables
var dashing: bool = false
var dash_timer: float = 0.0
var can_dash: bool = true
var player: Node2D

# Ready function
func _ready():
    player = get_parent()

# Process function
func _process(delta):
    update_dash(delta)

# Update dash
func update_dash(_delta):
    if player.is_on_floor():
        can_dash = true
    
    if dashing:
        perform_dash(_delta)

# Perform dash action
func perform_dash(_delta):
    player.velocity.y = 0
    player.velocity.x = dash_speed * (1 if player.animated_sprite.flip_h == false else - 1)
    dash_timer -= _delta
    player.animated_sprite.play("dash")
    if dash_timer <= 0:
        end_dash()

# Input handling for dashing
func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("dash"):
        if player and not dashing and can_dash:
            start_dash()

# Start dash action
func start_dash():
    can_dash = false
    dashing = true
    dash_timer = dash_duration

# End dash action
func end_dash():
    dashing = false


